# CAS 6.0 and Spring Security: JWT configuration fails on Service Ticket validation

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt, cas

I'm setting up a configuration using CAS 6.0 and Spring Boot with Spring Security so as to shift to JWT. Looking at [this](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/installation/Configure-ServiceTicket-JWT.html) guide, I've configured module dependency, CAS Service Registry, and signing and encryption Keys. The flow goes fine:

- calling the app at https://localhost:9000/secure/home/test I'm redirected to CAS login,
- at https://localhost:8443/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Flogin%2Fcas I can correctly specify credentials and see TGC in JWT form inside the cookies,
- after inserting credentials I'm redirected to https://localhost:9000/login/cas.

Last call has the two query string parameters redirect=true and ticket=[JWT string].
I've set up a filter decoding the token and it works, but then the filter chain hits CasAuthenticationFilter, which sees the ticket parameter and tries to validate it as Service Ticket, failing.

How can it be made aware of jwt, and forward the request to the original URL?

Answer (score 0):

the same question in CAS 5.3.x.

finally I did the following flow:

**CAS Server**:

1. set up the cas.properties in cas server, add 'cas.ticket.st.numberOfUse**s**=2' to let service ticket can be used twice. (default value is 1)

**Application Server**:

1. set up a filter to decode JWT token, extract service ticket from the key "jti" in JWT token.
2. set the response status to 302 and redirect to the request url and  make the service ticket as query string named "ticket". (note that in this step should not go on the next filter)
3. the redirect request from #2 should  not process in #1's filter then go on the filter chain.

The above flow works. But need more testing to confirm the working fine for web applications and result api service.

Comment: It sounds like a working solution. Unfortunately I changed my configuration to make it work and cannot test it unless rolling back everything. Anyway it still seems strange to me to implement this sort of a hack to avoid the error given by the CAS documented configuration. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I type a wrong key name, please correct cas.ticket.st.numberOfUser=2 to cas.ticket.st.numberOfUses=2. I have already correct my answer. Thanks